# Map from 2-sphere into $(\mathbb R^3, |\cdot|)$

Tags: general-topology, connectedness

Can you help me with this?

> Let $S^2 := \{x\in \mathbb R^3:||x||_2 = 1\} \subset (\mathbb R^3, ||\cdot||_2)$  and $T:S^2 \to (\mathbb R, |\cdot|)$ be a continuous map. Since $S^2$ is compact, $T$ attains its maximum $T_{max}$ and its minimum $T_{min}$.
>   Is there a value $T\in]T_{min},T_{max}[$ that is assumed at only one $x_0\in S^2$?

I think I have to use the fact that the image of a connected space under a continuous function is connected again, but I don't know how. Can you help?

Comment: Hint: $S^{2}$ partitions into level sets of $T$. What happens if some interior level of $T$ consists of exactly one point?

Comment: See this question here http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1840027/s-x-in-bbb-r3-x-2-1-and-t-s2-to-bbb-r-is-a-continuous/1840030#1840030

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the answer by @Hmm. expanded.

Suppose there was such a value. Then, there would exist a induced map $\widetilde{T}: S^2 \backslash \{x_0\} \to [T_{min},T[ \cup ]T,T_{max}]$, obtained by restricting the domain first, and then the image. This induced map is continuous by simple properties of continuity. But $S^2\backslash \{x_0\}$ is connected, since it is homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R^2}$. Therefore, the whole image must be inside either $[T_{min}, T[$ or $]T,T_{max}]$, which is absurd, since there is a point which is taken to $T_{min}$ and one which is taken to $T_{max}$.

Comment: Thanks. Now I understood it.

Comment: One more Question: What is $T$ in your Image? Just an arbitrary value?

Comment: @lappen68 The image of $x_0$.

Comment: Oh, of course. But it must be the open intervall $]T_{min},T[$ right?

Comment: $T$ must be in the open interval $]T_{min},T_{max}[$ in order to, when you excise him out, separate the set $[T_{min},T_{max}]$ in two connected components. Note that the proposition isn't true if $T$ is allowed to be the extreme values. Just consider the height function on the sphere.

Answer (score 3):

$\textbf{Hint:}$ Assume such a point exists. Remove its pre-image from $\mathbb{S}^2$ and restrict $T$ to this space. Now you use the fact that a continuous image of a connected space is connected.

Comment: But $T$ does not need to be continuous anymore after removing that point from its domain, does it? Even if it does, I am not really sure how to continue. What you said is as far as I have gotten so far.

Comment: @lappen68 The restriction of a continuous function is always continuous on the induced topology.